# Find the coordinates of B = (sin(θ), cos(θ)) and C = (2 sin(θ) + cos(θ), 3 cos(θ))

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not sure where to start with this one. I need to eventually find the transition matrix from B to C, but I know I need to find the coords to create a 2x2 matrix.

B = (sin(θ), cos(θ)) and C = (2 sin(θ) + cos(θ), 3 cos(θ))

Comment: If you mean coordinates with respect to a basis, you will need to say what the basis is.

Comment: I just need to have a matrix in R2 so that I can find the transition matrix of this. But, I assumed I need to find the coords to form that matrix. What would be the R2 in which I can find the transition matrix from B to C? @David